# How to convert zip file to stream in JavaScript and send that stream to C# WebAPI which accepts stream as input.(For file upload)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

Am having a zip file which needs to be sent to Asp.Net WebAPI from frontend browser.
My WebAPI accepts a stream as input. So how can I convert zip to stream in frontend(in javascript) and make a post request to WebAPI which accepts the stream?

Comment: Note:- In WebAPI I'll read the stream and update that steam data to a database.